# Remove <xsl:if> statements? Looking for an alternative

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XSLT.  I have written the following, which tests to see if `/Config/Service/Groups/Group[x]` exists, and if so, it adds `Route` and uses the value-of `Group[x]/name` for dGroup.

```
<xsl:if test="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[2]">
    <Route>
        <match>.*1202.*</match>
        <type>E</type>
        <dGroup>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[2]/name"/>
        </dGroup>
    </Route>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[3]">
    <Route>
        <match>.*1203.*</match>
        <type>E</type>
        <dGroup>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[3]/name"/>
        </dGroup>
    </Route>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[3]">
    <Route>
        <match>1311</match>
        <type>A</type>
        <dGroup>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[3]/name"/>
        </dGroup>
    </Route>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[4]">
    <Route>
        <match>2311</match>
        <type>A</type>
        <dGroup>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[4]/name"/>
        </dGroup>
    </Route>
</xsl:if>
<xsl:if test="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[5]">
    <Route>
        <match>3311</match>
        <type>A</type>
        <dGroup>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[5]/name"/>
        </dGroup>
    </Route>
</xsl:if>
```

I have to check for and add Routes for 9 and only 9 of these Groups, if they exist. There may be multiple Routes per group with a different match element in every Route. Using so many if statements seems a little clunky, but I can't figure out how to write it better since the match element changes as well as the Group.

Is there a more proper way to do this in XSLT?

Here is the xml:

```
<Config>
    <Service>
        <Groups>
            <Group>
                <name>cs</name>
                <extension>501</extension>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <name>ab</name>
                <extension>602</extension>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <name>bu</name>
                <extension>703</extension>
            </Group>
            <Group>
                <name>ch</name>
                <extension>804</extension>
            </Group>
        </Groups>
    </Service>
</Config>
```

Comment: Yes, there is. Would you mind editing your question with the relevant part of your XML so that we have a [mcve] to work on?

Comment: @zx485 Sorry for the delay, I will do that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use a data island with the mapping for each `Group`. Another would be using a separate file for storing these mappings.

In this example I chose the former one.
The code uses the `position()` of the `Group` element for the mapping. Of course there are other possibilities.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:gKey="http://gkey.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Data island with mapping (could be moved to a separate file -->
    <gKey:keys>
        <key num="2" match=".*1202.*" type="E" />
        <key num="3" match=".*1203.*" type="E" />
        <key num="3" match="1311"     type="A" />
        <key num="4" match="2311"     type="A" />
        <key num="5" match="3311"     type="A" />
    </gKey:keys>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <!-- Iterate over all <Group>s -->
        <xsl:for-each select="Config/Service/Groups/Group">
            <xsl:variable name="pos" select="position()" />
            <xsl:variable name="nam" select="/Config/Service/Groups/Group[$pos]/name" />
            <!-- Iterate over all keys for this <Group> -->
            <xsl:for-each select="document('')/*/gKey:keys/key[@num = $pos]">
                <!-- Compose the <Route> element -->
                <Route>
                    <match><xsl:value-of select="@match" /></match>
                    <type><xsl:value-of  select="@type" /></type>
                    <dGroup>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$nam"/>
                    </dGroup>
                </Route>  
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>  

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
<Route>
    <match>.*1202.*</match>
    <type>E</type>
    <dGroup>Groupie Two</dGroup>
</Route>
<Route>
    <match>.*1203.*</match>
    <type>E</type>
    <dGroup>Groupie Three</dGroup>
</Route>
<Route>
    <match>1311</match>
    <type>A</type>
    <dGroup>Groupie Three</dGroup>
</Route>
<Route>
    <match>2311</match>
    <type>A</type>
    <dGroup>Groupie Four</dGroup>
</Route>
<Route>
    <match>3311</match>
    <type>A</type>
    <dGroup>Groupie Five</dGroup>
</Route>
```

Comment: Works like a charm.  You're brilliant.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: I tried to look up more about gKey and didn't see anything out there.  Is there somewhere to read about it?

Comment: `gKey` is just an arbitrary namespace defined in the `xsl:stylesheet` element with `xmlns:gKey="http://gkey.com"`. It is a method of embedding XML data in an XSLT-stylesheet, similar to an XML data island and is accessed via `document('')/*/`. You could use a separate file instead of this approach and access it with `document('external_file')/`.